# Why can't nmap identify the danted(socks5) service on non-standard port?

Tags: firewalls, nmap

I'm testing nmap's abilities, I started a socks5 proxy server with danted, and started it on port `10090`

I tried the following command, and expect it to tell me port 10090 runs a socks server,

```
nmap ubuntu -p 10900 -sV -A
```

But it only tells me the port is open.

```
%> nmap ubuntu -p 10900 -sV -A

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-03-18 12:45 CST
Nmap scan report for ubuntu (172.16.177.200)
Host is up (0.00026s latency).
PORT      STATE SERVICE VERSION
10900/tcp open  unknown

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.76 seconds
```

Did I miss something? It works perfectly if the socks server listens on port 1080

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nmap detects SOCKS proxies via 2 service probes defined in the `nmap-service-probes` file:

```
Probe TCP Socks4 q|\x04\x01\x00\x16\x7f\x00\x00\x01root\x00|
rarity 8
ports 199,1080,1090,1095,1100,1105,1109,3128,6588,6660-6669,8000,8008,8080,8088
```

and

```
Probe TCP Socks5 q|\x05\x04\x00\x01\x02\x80\x05\x01\x00\x03\x0agoogle.com\x00\x50GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n|
rarity 8
ports 199,1080,1090,1095,1100,1105,1109,3128,6588,6660-6669,7777,8000,8008,8010,8080,8088,9481
```

These probes will be sent to the ports listed. The `rarity 8` part means that they will only run on non-matching ports if you specified a `--version-intensity` of 8 or more. The default is 7, the maximum is 9.